# 1D Saliency map for 4D input

Tags: pytorch, computer-vision

I have a tensor with dims (frames, channels, height, width).

Each image is converted to a vector representation through a pretrained encoder. Then it is passed through an LSTM. I want to generate saliency map that highlights the most important frames.

Can I just do a normal saliency map and the sum the frames or do I have to do something else?

Comment: A little more info/code about what you're using to generate this may be helpful. Also worth noting, saliency maps determine the location of important things, not how important they are. You're looking to figure out what frames are important? Does your saliency map generate much output on unimportant frames?